# The number of visits made by a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let the initial state of a MC, $X_{0}=i$, be fixed.

> Definition: $T=\left\{n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}:X_{n}=i \right\}$ is the time of the first visit from i to i.
>
> Definition: $\pi\left(i\right)$ is the expected amount of time a MC remains in a state i.

If a MC makes k=K number of visits to a state i, starting at state i, the expected time for **one** visit to a state i, starting at state i, is $\frac{1}{K} \sum_{\mathscr{k=1}}^{K}$=
$\frac{T^{1}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot T^{K}}{K}=E[T]$

For K number of visits to a state i starting from state i, the amount of time spent by the MC is $K E[T]$.

> Claim: In time n, the number of visits made by a MC from a state i to a state i is $n \pi\left(i\right)$ such that $n=K E[T]$.

How do I understand that $n \pi\left(i\right)$ is the number of visits made by a MC?

Any help is appreciated.

Edit @Michael:

There are about K visits to the state i in $kE[T]$ steps/ time of the MC. **But, in n steps we expect about $n\pi\left(i\right)$ visits to the state i**.
Hence, setting $n=KE[T]$, we get $E[T]=\pi^{-1}\left(i\right)$

Comment: The claims and statements are a bit off. Some of your statements confuse random variables, expectations, and steady state probabilities. For example, (i) The equation $\frac{T^1+...+T^K}{K}=E[T]$ has a random variable on the left and an expectation on the right; (ii) The "number of visits" is an integer and likely a random variable, it cannot be $n\pi(i)$ (which might even be non-integer).  I think you really mean to ask, if you define $\pi(i)$ as the steady state fraction of time being in state $i$, why is $\pi(i) = 1/E[T]$?

Comment: @Michael Thank you for shedding light on my doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  To make your writing a bit more clear I would change "There are about $k=K$ visits" to the cleaner and more direct "There are about $k$ visits."  No need to confuse people with an unclear distinction between $k$ and $K$.